# Purpose of Includes directory in Magento, Shell Directory, Api.php and get.php

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

i'm new in Magento, please let me know what is basic purpose on Include directory in Magento and how it's work? and also i want to know about Shell directory, Api php file in root directory of magento and get php file also in root directory. Can anyone explain it's confusing me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `includes` directory is used for storing compiled code and config of Magento Compiler (see System > Configuration > Tools > Magento Compiler)
- `shell` directory is used for CLI tools to perform maintenance tasks from command line, script names located there are self-explanatory
- `api.php` is used for API requests from various integrations (i.e. ERP system or POS terminals)
- `get.php` is used when you store media files in database instead of filesystem. It can be useful if you have multiply backends or host a huge shared Magento install like "Magento Go"